# running into trouble with constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I run into trouble while initializing a class with constants:

Why the initialisation with a pointer to a member in the same class results into an error?
The error comes up without using the class "Use"!

```
class A
{   
    private:
        int a;
        const int* const aptr;

    public:
        constexpr A( int _a):
            a(_a)
           , aptr( &a)           // why aptr could not be initialized? 
    {}  
};  

class Data { } d1; 

class B
{   
    private:
        Data* dptr1;

    public:
        constexpr B(Data* _p): dptr1( _p) {}

};  

class Use 
{   
    static constexpr A a{2};   // fail! error: field initializer is not constant
    static constexpr B b{&d1}; // works
};
```

Comment: @Morwenn: By the time `aptr` is being constructed, `a` has already been constructed and has a valid address.

Comment: I you initialize `A` and `B` outisde of `Use` with g++, you get `sorry, unimplemented: use of the value of the object being constructed in a constant expression`.

Comment: I think you either have a typo or UB here: You're taking the address of a function parameter, that doesn't exist any more after the ctor of `A` has finished. Maybe you want `constexpr A(int& _a)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is valid, and Clang accepts it; this seems to be a g++ bug. The address of `Use::a.a` is an address constant expression, since it evaluates to the address of an object with static storage duration, so it can be used to initialize a `constexpr` object.

Comment: I think you mean gcc.gnu.org/PR57694

Comment: Sorry, you are right. The bug report is http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57694